# Click event of LinkButton doesn't call when i add it from code behind

Tags: asp.net

I use below code for set click to `LinkButton` but doesn't call the event,when i click on linkbutton,it 's hiding

```
LinkButton lnk = new LinkButton();
lnk.Text = "....";
lnk.Click+=new EventHandler(lnk_Click);
pnl.Controls.Add(lnk); // pnl is Panel in GridView's cell

//event
protected void lnk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You also have to set the `void` to `protected`

`protected void lnk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { }`

And in the markup, you need to add `OnClick="lnk_Click"` on your `LinkButton`.

Edit: I noticed that you are creating the `LinkButton` from code behind.

To add the `OnClick` event you can use `lnk.Attributes.Add("onclick", Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(this, lnk.ID.ToString()));`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms153112.aspx

Comment: i set it to (protected) but still doesn't call

Comment: i add `lnk.Click+=new EventHandler(lnk_Click);`

Comment: Yes, but if you check the source, it won't have a `OnClick`-event registered in the HTML for the link. If you look at my edit, you will see I added some more code.

Comment: if you mean that i add `lnk.Attributes.Add("onclick", Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(this, lnk.ID.ToString()));`  i add it but again doesn't call

Comment: Must the button be created from code behind? Can't it be defined in the panel in your markup?

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
LinkButton lnk = new LinkButton();
lnk.Text = "....";
lnk.Click+=new EventHandler(lnk_Click);
pnl.Controls.Add(lnk); // pnl is Panel in GridView's cell


protected void lnk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
LinkButton lnk = sender as LinkButton;
// your work
}
```

Comment: i set it to (protected) but still doesn't call